# Rich text box .rtf string is not the same as copying the text with cut and paste. How to get the same format?

Tags: ms-word, clipboard, copy-paste, richtext

How can I copy rich text from a rich text box to the clipboard in ***exactly the same format*** that I would acquire if I were to highlight the content of a rich text box and copy it with control-c?

I know how to copy the rich text string by using ".rtf" (and I know how to copy plain text), ***but these do not return the same results***.  If I highlight the material in a rich text box and copy it and then paste it into Word the formatting remains perfect.  Word accepts the content as colored, having bullets, having italics or bold or different fonts sizes, or whatever.  But if I copy the rich text with .rtf into the clipboard and pass that into word then I just see the rich text codes.  Plain text (.text), of course, just gives me plain text.

What I am looking for is the ability for the user to stick together the content of multiple rich text boxes into the clipboard in such a way that she/he can paste them directly into a ***normal/standard*** Word document and other editors that would be compatible.  In other words I want the content to go into the clipboard ***just as if the user had selected the text and copied it and then pasted it***, but I wish to append the text from multiple sources together depending on user selections and the program state.

I know that clipboard manager programs exist (that is not what I am writing) and I am imagine that at least some of them are written in C, so I am guessing that this must be possible.

Comment: What I can tell you is that Word uses a converter when bringing in non-native content (native content being Word Open XML), whether inserting a file or pasting from the Clipboard. If the content you're putting on the Clipboard is coming through with the RTF mark-up showing, then Word is "seeing" the content as "plain text". So it likely has something to do with the command or parameters you're using to put the content on the Clipboard - that's where you should concentrate your efforts.

Comment: Woohoo!  That was super helpful.  It told me right where to look.  Thanks Cindy!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Cindy I found my answer.  I didn't realize that  Clipboard.SetText required one to set the format to RTF if one was copying from an RTF source.

That solved the problem and opened my eyes to some new possibilities as well.

Thanks again.